# How to export UIView to PDF file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, export

I implement exporting PDF feature in my application, content used to export is `UIView`. Now I have a list data and use for loop to load all objects, every object will be loaded in `UIView` and export a page. The output file should have multipage but it has only one first page.

Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path, CGRectZero, nil);
_context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for (Entry *entry in listEntries) {
    [self loadEntry:entry.date];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0.0f, -160.0f, 768.0f, 660.0f), nil);
    [self.layer renderInContext:_context];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I made a mistake when putting UIGraphicsEndPDFContext() inside for loop. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `UIGraphicsEndPDFPageWithInfo()` or something like that? You need to decide when your content will spill over, and start a new page before rendering it to the PDF. At least that's what I used to do when I used CoreGraphics to do this kind of thing. If there is no `EndPage` function, perhaps just another call to `BeginPage` will do the trick.