# Export text or pdf

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, text, export

In my app, user can add some information to his list and finally he want to send that list by email to someone else. I just wonder how can I export that list ? is it posible to export it as pdf or txt file ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I used this code, unfortunately I lost the page that I found the answer so sorry about not referencing it. this is the magic code :

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, mainView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [mainView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
//    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are searching for iOS5 then check [this Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1).

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

**EDIT** : use `UI` `elements` like this:

```
 [yourView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]
```

Comment: thanks Siba, I red that tutorial before, i just wonder if it is possible to use the current UILabel or UIView that I already created in my xib file,instead of NSString* textToDraw = @"Hello World"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554670/how-to-export-uiview-to-pdf-file this might help you.